# Elastic Search/Tire: How to map to association attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire) for Elastic Search. In my application I have 2 models; Price and Product.

I'm trying to search my Price class and use the Product it belongs to's `:name` attribute for the search field. Right now if I had a product called `Product 1` and type in "pro", "prod" or "duct", no results come up. But typing "product" or "Product" shows the results. I believe the problem lies in my mapping. I looked at the query and its:

```
...localhost:3000/search/results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=product
```

When I think it should be:

```
...localhost:3000/search/results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query:product=product
```

Judging by this question: [ElasticSearch mapping doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226546/elasticsearch-mapping-doesnt-work)

I don't know how to make my `params[:query]` to take the `product.name` only though. I tried to use: `string params[:query], default_field: "product.name"` but that didn't work.

I don't want to use the `_all` field.

Here is my code:

**Price.rb**

```
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
       query do
         boolean do
            must { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
            must { term :private, false }
         end
       end
       sort do
         by :date, "desc"
         by :amount, "asc"
       end
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json( include: { product: { only: [:name] } } )
  end

  mapping do
    indexes :id,        type: "integer"
    indexes :amount,    type: "string", index: "not_analyzed"
    indexes :date,      type: "date",   index: "not_analyzed"
    indexes :private,   type: "boolean"
    indexes :product do
      indexes :name, type: "string", analyzer: "custom_analyzer"
    end
  end

  settings analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      custom_analyzer: {
        tokenizer: [ "whitespace", "lowercase" ],
        filter: [ "ngram_filter", "word_delimiter_filter" ],
        type: "custom"
      }
    },
    filter: {
      ngram_filter: {
        type: "nGram",
        min_gram: 2,
        max_gram: 15
      }
    },
    filter: {
      word_delimiter_filter: {
        type: "word_delimiter",
        generate_word_parts: true,
        generate_number_parts: true,
        preserve_original: true,
        stem_english_possessive: true
      }
    }
  }
```

So does anyone have any suggestions or know how to set the query field to use the Product name only?

Thank you.

Comment: I will have to work on this very same issue in a very near future. So I will update with my progress, unless you beat me to it!

Comment: @Alain I'm still working on this, so if you have any idea how to get this to work, let me know. Your progress would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was to much of a headache so I ended going to [Ransack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) which was insanely much easier to figure out and use.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
 query   { string params[:query] }
```

and the query doesn't specify a field, you're searching the magic `_all` field. This field has its own analyzer settings - it's won't be using the one you've setup for your name field.

You can either configure the `_all` field to use your analyser, change the default analyser or change your query to query the `name` field specifically, for example

```
 query { string params[:query], :default_field => 'name'}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on `default_field => 'name'`. Where did you find this out at? If I was trying to use the `product.name` field. How would that happen?

Comment: This isn't working for me. Is my mapping to the `product.name` correct? I think that's why it's not working.

Comment: Oh, you probably want to set default field to product.name, hadn't spotted the nested-ness of your mapping

Comment: So I just do: `must { string params[:query], :default_field => "product.name" }`? Because its not working. I have no clue where to go from here but I'm still looking around.

Comment: Still doing what I can to figure this out. I changed around my code entirely up above.

Comment: Have you tried a text query with an explicit field? Have you checked that elastic search has picked up your settings (for settings like analyser I think you have to recreate the index when you change them)

Comment: If you mean this `:default_field => 'name'` or this `:default_field => 'product.name'`, then yes and both will return no search results. By pick up settings, the only thing I run is `$ rake environment tire:import CLASS='Price' FORCE=true`. Maybe it's my Rails and Tire version that is the problem ( `"rails", "3.1.0"`, `"tire", "0.4.2"`)

Comment: I mean use a query of type text rather than string. Worth poking around to see if elasticsearch is actually using the mapping you've given (have a look at the settings and mappin apis)

Comment: I think your right. The mapping is not happening I believe. I updated my code to show you a strange error. I change my `query_string` and got an error.

Comment: OK, so I believe the `settings` block isn't working. Not sure why though. My Update 2 explains in more.

Comment: I'd try deleting the index and then letting tire recreate it

Comment: The only way I know of deleting is by doing `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Price' FORCE=true`. It doesn't have a rake command to delete I think.

Comment: OK, so I don't think it's the settings, it's the mapping. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Just went to use Ransack instead. Way easier to figure out.